# How do I get a callback function to print something only periodically?

Tags: python, callback

```
 def callback(data):
        global sizeWritten
        file.write(data)
        sizeWritten += len(data)
        a = sizeWritten/totalSize*100
        print("Downloading " + item + ":" + str(int(a)) + " %")
```

This function is called upon after every chunk of file I download. If the file is fairly large I quickly end up with millions of lines of output. I would like it to print a line after every successfully downloaded 5%. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another variable called `totalProgress` outside your method and initialize it to 0. Then you can do `global totalProgress` just like you did for `global sizeWritten`.

Then you can do it as follows:

## Your Code

```
totalProgress = 0.0    #this is a percentage value

def callback(data):
    global sizeWritten
    global totalProgress
    file.write(data)
    sizeWritten += len(data)
    a = (sizeWritten/totalSize)*100.0
    if a - totalProgress > 5.0:
        print("Downloading " + item + ":" + str(int(a)) + " %")
        totalProgress = a
```